# iOS-style toggle button

Tags: android, user-interface, togglebutton

I wanted to make toggle buttons in my activity look something like the picture below, is there something like this for android in standard classes? Or maybe there is a tutorial on how to imitate them? I looked, but found none.
Thanks for your replies :3

[I couldn't insert the reference image, so here's the link to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4rxm.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [searched](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android+custom+togglebutton) but [found none](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/07/sexily-styled-toggle-buttons-for-android/)? Methink you're not searching hard enough. There's a ton of tutorials out there that explain how.

Comment: okaaaay, that was really stupid of me to put the word "ios" in my google query. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianDupuis 2nd link ("found none") is dead.

Comment: @DavidAndreoletti here's an archive of that site if you so desire: http://archive.li/adXAq